# richfaces and displaying errormessages

Tags: jsf, richfaces

```
        <h:form id="userSettingsForm">
            <rich:messages>
                <f:facet name="errorMarker">
                    <h:graphicImage value="/img/msgerror.png" />
                </f:facet>
            </rich:messages>


            <h:outputText value="Description:" />
            <h:inputText label="Description:" id="description"
                value="#{userSettingsForm.instance.description}" required="true"
                size="5">
                <f:validateLength minimum="3" />
            </h:inputText>

            <a:commandButton value="Validate" />

        </h:form>
```

When an error occurs I see e.g. this: [screenshot](http://rl-dev.com/tmp/err1.png)

How can I display the text "Description" in front of "Required field" ?

Like it is used on the richfaces demo page at [richfaces demo page](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/messages.jsf?c=messages&tab=usage)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that I was missing something in my messages_en.properties file.

When I create one using `seam setup` the generated file contains e.g. this:

`javax.faces.converter.IntegerConverter.INTEGER=Value is not a number`
`javax.faces.component.UIInput.REQUIRED=Required field`

When I add:

`javax.faces.converter.IntegerConverter.INTEGER={2}: Value is not a number` 
or
`javax.faces.component.UIInput.REQUIRED={0}: Required field`

The field label is added in front of the message.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [`<rich:message>`](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/rich_message.html) - it shows a single message.